# over-the-air deployment of iPhone app

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Does anyone have any idea on how to perform over-the-air, deployment of an iPhone app?

Apple's document say that enterprise applications can be distributed OTA, but don't describe , how to go about it.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess when I asked this question, wireless app distribution was not supported. But it is supported since iOS 4.0. In case anyone stumbles upon this question...check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Also you can do testing of this feature using http://www.diawi.com/

Answer (score 3):

I didn't even know *Over the Air* was [official](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) for so long now! Anyway, first OTA service I've met was [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/), which is very much like that [diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) you've pointed.

And here I'll quote this [great guide I've found about AdHoc OTA with XCode](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html):

> If you’ve been through the distribution process of an Ad Hoc application, you can appreciate the challenges of getting a build installed on someone’s device. From the differences of working with users on Windows versus Mac machines, to explaining how to import an Ad Hoc provisioning file and the associated build into iTunes, this process is anything but a walk in the park.
>
> (...) deploying Ad Hoc builds over-the-air, where users simply point the Safari web-browser (on their iPhone) to a link and tap to install the provisioning file and associated application.

Just to highlight the distinct advantage of deploying over the air.

Comment: Thanks Cawas for ur input. Will go through this.

Comment: @Vin you're welcome! And thanks for your self-answered question too. :)